# Any shortcut or open source code can format a JSON String with proper indentation in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, json, nsstring

## Problem:

Every time, when I got a JSON string from Web Server, it looks like this:

```
{"array":[1,2,3],"boolean":true,"null":null,"number":123,"object":{"a":"b","c":"d","e":"f"},"string":"Hello World"}
```

I really wanna re-organise string format to NSLog() it like this:

```
{
  "array": [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ],
  "boolean": true,
  "null": null,
  "number": 123,
  "object": {
    "a": "b",
    "c": "d",
    "e": "f"
  },
  "string": "Hello World"
}
```

### Question:

Is there any shortcut to format JSON NSString with proper indentation and line feeds?  (I know [NSDictionary description])

### P.S.

Sometimes, the JSON NSString has prefix string like this:

```
  Web Service response is : {"array":[1,2,3],"boolean":true,"null":null,"number":123,"object":{"a":"b","c":"d","e":"f"},"string":"Hello World"}
```

Any method or regular-expression can grab JSON string out of the paragraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code that will strip leading characters up to the first curly brace and display the JSON data nicely formatted on the debug console.

```
NSRange range = [str rangeOfString:@"{"];
if ( range.location != NSNotFound )
    str = [str substringFromIndex:range.location];

NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

NSLog( @"%@", jsonData );
```

Comment: You are right! We don't need to reinvent the wheel. Your solution is perfect! But it's not JSON format String.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
 NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:temp options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil ];
 NSString* aStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

 NSLog(@"result: %@", aStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to parse it to an Object first and see what happens if you print it then. With a little luck the textual representation of Array's and Dictionaries will get you on your way. Right now you are printing a string, which will always look a little something like that.

Obviously you could write some code that recognizes the curly brackets and commas and based on that adds in line-endings and indentations. Should not be too hard, but the question is why would you want that?

If you use it to debug, just put a breakpoint there and look at the object in your code in XCode with the inspector. That will show you the object and the objects withing and give you an option to print it's representation to the console.

Comment: I just wanna make my debug console looks neat. It is hard to find information in un-indented string like this: {"array":[1,2,3],"boolean":true,"null":null,"number":123,"object":{"a":"b","c":"d","e":"f"},"string":"Hello World"}